# Problem with pivot table - information is squeezed in one row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to get my data into a better structure by converting it back to wide format using pivot table (Pandas).

Please see below for an example, where I selected data for one specific id.

As you can see, there is a running index for each id because one id can have several type_ids, descriptions etc. (see column buildingTypes_). In the example below, the id has two type_ids, descriptions etc. (index 0 and index 1).

```
id  suffix  originId    buildingTypes_  index
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    type_id 10BX107385  102 0
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    description 10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser  0
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    developmentTypeId   10BX107385  5502    0
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    developmentTypeDescription  10BX107385  Umbau   0
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    insertDate  10BX107385  2011-09-29T09:41:53.830+01:00   0
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    type_id 10BX107385  102 1
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    description 10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser  1
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    developmentTypeId   10BX107385  5503    1
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    developmentTypeDescription  10BX107385  Äussere Veränderungen   1
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    insertDate  10BX107385  2011-09-29T09:42:06.750+01:00   1
```

I am doing the following:

```
df_w = df.pivot_table(index=["id", "originId"], 
    columns=['suffix'], values = 'buildingTypes_', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)).reset_index()
```

which yields the following data:

```
suffix  id  originId    description developmentTypeDescription  developmentTypeId   insertDate  type_id
0   00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser...   Umbau Äussere Veränderungen 5502 5503   2011-09-29T09:41:53.830+01:00 2011-09-29T09:42...   102 102
```

Even though the columns are in the right structure, I want to have two rows in this case (as there are two index values).

My desired output would be:

```
originId    description developmentTypeDescription  developmentTypeId   insertDate  type_id
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser   Umbau   5502   2011-09-29T09:41:53.830+01:00   102
00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser  Äussere Veränderungen   5503    2011-09-29T09:42:06.750+01:00   102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap matrices in pivot, duplicate items are not allowed, so we split the data frame by index values and recombine the transformed ones in pivot. There may be other, cooler ways to do this.

```
df_0 = df[df['index'] == 0]
df_1 = df[df['index'] == 1]
df_0_w = df_0.pivot(index=["id", "originId"], columns='suffix', values='buildingTypes_').reset_index()
df_1_w = df_1.pivot(index=["id", "originId"], columns='suffix', values='buildingTypes_').reset_index()
df_w = pd.concat([df_0_w, df_1_w], ignore_index=True)

df_w
suffix  id  originId    description     developmentTypeDescription  developmentTypeId   insertDate  type_id
0   00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser  Umbau   5502    2011-09-29T09:41:53.830+01:00   102
1   00008a4a-6564-4fb4-9e8f-c60d40275ceb    10BX107385  Wohnen (ab 3 Wohneinheiten)-Mehrfamilienhäuser  Äussere Veränderungen   5503    2011-09-29T09:42:06.750+01:00   102
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I was able to implement a solution based on the suggestion above. The number of index values can vary by id, thus I use a loop:

```
df_ = {}
df_w = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df['index'].unique() :
    df_[i] = df[df['index'] == str(i)]
    df_[i] = df_[i].pivot_table(index=["id", "originId"], columns='suffix', values='buildingTypes_', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)).reset_index()
    df_w = pd.concat([df_w, df_[i]], ignore_index = True)
```